# SUSE chkconfig --add no longer works

Tags: linux, daemon, opensuse

I maintain a package that runs some services for datalogger communication. I am getting complaints that these services are not running after the package is installed in the latest version of opensuse.  Currently, my postinst script for the package looks like the following:

```
/sbin/chkconfig --add csilgrnet
/sbin/service csilgrnet start
```

This, of course is executed by the package manager after the csilgrnet file has been added to /etc/init.d

Looking at the /etc/init.d directory, the only service scripts that I see there are the ones placed there by my package.  I don't see the scripts there for any other packages or parts of the distribution.  It would thus appear to me that the way that daemon startup scripts ways are managed has changed but I am clueless about the alternative.

Comment: I don't know what version you're running, but it's likely that SuSE is using systemd and everything else has already been migrated to use it.  Redhat does a similar thing to allow old init.d style scripts to work, but they'll cease that support in the future.

Comment: FWIW, [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) is probably a better place for this question.